# FireBase user authentication redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have created a signupPage.html to authenticate a user and and log information to the realtime database in firebase using this code:

```
 signUp_button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        
            .then((userCredential) => {
                //signed up
                const user = userCredential.user;
                
                
                //log to database
                set(ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid),{
                    email : email
                })
                //this is where page redirection
                
                alert('User Created');
            })
            
            .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;

                alert(errorMessage);
                
            });
    });
```

Then when I click my submit button everything works and the user is authenticated and information is stored into the realtime database. Now I want to redirect the user to a login page after they submit their signup. In my code under "this is where page redirection", I put location.href = "login.html". This does redirect the page and authenticate the user but it no longer stores the data into the realtime database. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You were close. `set()` is an asynchronous action, so by adding the redirect where you were, you would redirect before the `set()` had the chance to execute. You must first wait for the `set()` to finish, and then redirect.

```
signUp_button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(async (userCredential) => {
      //signed up
      const user = userCredential.user;
                
      // log to database & wait for it to finish!
      return set(ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid), {
        email : email
      })
    })
    .then(() => {
      alert('User Created'); // avoid alert, it blocks user input!
                             // update a div with an information message instead
    
      location.href = "login.html";
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;

      alert(errorMessage);   // avoid alert, it blocks user input!
                             // update a div with an error message instead
    });
});
```